# When using struct inheritance in GML, how do you make a call to the parent's version of a function?

Tags: gml, game-maker-studio-2

In most languages with a class system, there's some way to call the "base" version of a method from within an overriding method. It's usually called something like `super` or `base`. I know GML's "object-oriented" features are new and still not entirely there, but I was wondering whether there was a way to do the same thing in GML.

To be clear, I know how to do this with event inheritance (the `event_inherited` function), but here we're talking about the functions of structs, not the event responses of game objects. I also know that this can be done with struct *constructors*; I'm wondering if there's an equivalent for the struct's other functions.

An example of what I'm talking about. Let's say I have the following two kinds of structs:

```
function Animal(_name) constructor {
    name = _name;
    
    static Speak = function() {
        show_debug_message(name + " makes noise");
    }
}

function Dog(_name) : Animal(_name + " the dog") constructor {
    static Speak = function() {
        base.Speak(); // <-- THIS DOESN'T WORK, OBVIOUSLY
        show_debug_message("(The kind of noise a dog would make)");
    }
}
```

And I do this:

```
var bonzo = new Dog("Bonzo");
bonzo.Speak();
```

Then the output I'm looking for would be:

```
Bonzo the dog makes noise
(The kind of noise a dog would make)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GameMaker does not have a conventional `base` keyword, but static variables are still variables, so you can get the parent field before you "override" it in a child constructor:

```
function Animal(_name) constructor {
    name = _name;
    
    static Speak = function() {
        show_debug_message(name + " makes noise");
    }
}
function Dog(_name) : Animal(_name + " the dog") constructor {
    static Animal_Speak = Speak;
    static Speak = function() {
        Animal_Speak(); // <-- THIS DOESN'T WORK, OBVIOUSLY
        show_debug_message("(The kind of noise a dog would make)");
    }
}
function SmallDog(_name) : Dog(_name + " (small)") constructor {
    static Dog_Speak = Speak;
    static Speak = function() {
        Dog_Speak();
        show_debug_message("(except high-pitched)");
    }
}
```

```
var dog = new SmallDog("Bonzo");
    dog.Speak();
```

```
Bonzo (small) the dog makes noise
(The kind of noise a dog would make)
(except high-pitched)
```